# Is it correct and natural to say, 'we are a family'?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural, sentence-choice

I read in the subtitles of a show such a sentence,

> We are a family.

This sounds kind of weird to me. It's unusual to see 'are' followed by an 'a'.
Besides, when I googled 'we are a family', the results are almost all titled 'we are family'.

So, I suspect instead of 'we are a family', one should say 'we are family'. Is my guess correct?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct depending on context.

1. 'We are a family' is like 'We collectively make up a single group called X' eg 'We are a group of superheroes known as the X-Men/Avengers.' Also the line 'we're a family' was in Breaking Bad. But don't look it up if you haven't watched. It's a spoiler.
2. 'We are family' - I'm sure you're aware of the [Sister Sledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Are_Family_(song)) song. This is using 'family' as an adjective now. I think this has some stronger kinship connotation. Eg

- 'We are family members' is like 'We are Americans', stating a matter of fact.
- 'We are family' is like 'We are America', suggesting something more than mere denotation.

Of course, the usage of 'We are America' sounds like it comes from some inspirational speech either very patriotic or very nationalistic. Can't quite think of a better analogy.

P.S. I'm a monolinguist, but I'm not American. [Wesley So on the other hand is American. (I think.)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324239/african-american-or-filipino-american-how-do-you-distinguish-americans-of-a)